# How to create unique li with unique group name

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me, how to create unique li with unique group name, i have written below code. I am taking html value of ul and generating li with for loop based of some code logic and wanted to achieve result as per expected output.

Can anyone help me to achieve the functionality as per expected output?

```
let chosenResultsUl = document.getElementsByClassName("chosen-results");

const array1 = [
  {
    group: null,
    id: "all-categories",
    title: "Search All",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null,
  },
  {
    group: null,
    id: "trial-catalog",
    title: "Aspire Free Products",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "taqman-assays",
    title: "TaqMan Assays",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: null,
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "gene-exp-assays",
    title: "Gene Expression",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "microbe-abr-detection",
    title: "Microbe & ABR Detection",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: null,
  },
  {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "microbe-detection",
    title: "Microbe Detection",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "antibiotic-resistance",
    title: "Antibiotic Resistance",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "crispr-guide-rna",
    title: "CRISPR Guide RNA",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
];
let chosenResultsLi = [];

for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      if (array1[i].group === null) {
        chosenResultsLi.push(
          `<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index=${i}>${array1[i].title}</li>`
        );
      } else {
        chosenResultsLi.push(
          `<li class="group-result" data-option-array-index=${i}>${array1[i].group}</li>
            <li class="active-result group-option" data-option-array-index=${i}>${array1[i].title}</li>
          `
        );
      }
    }

let html = "";
    if (chosenResultsLi.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < chosenResultsLi?.length; i++) {
        html += chosenResultsLi[i];
      }
      focusAreaSelector.classList.add("chosen-container-active", "chosen-with-drop");
    }
    chosenResultsUl[0].innerHTML = html;
```

Current Output ---

[image]

Expected Output ---

[image]

Comment: Can you share your HTML code as well?

Comment: lodash `groupBy`

Comment: Hi @ElsonRamos, HTML - `<ul class="chosen-results"></ul>`

Comment: What is that focusAreaSelector variable?

Comment: @ElsonRamos, that is nothing ... just adding some extra classes into some html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code block will help you to get expected output**

You need transform your array

```
const array1 = [
  {
    group: null,
    id: "all-categories",
    title: "Search All",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null,
  },
  {
    group: null,
    id: "trial-catalog",
    title: "Aspire Free Products",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "taqman-assays",
    title: "TaqMan Assays",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: null,
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "gene-exp-assays",
    title: "Gene Expression",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "microbe-abr-detection",
    title: "Microbe & ABR Detection",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: null,
  },
  {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "microbe-detection",
    title: "Microbe Detection",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "antibiotic-resistance",
    title: "Antibiotic Resistance",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
  {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "crispr-guide-rna",
    title: "CRISPR Guide RNA",
    searchURL: "",
    typeAheadURL: "",
    include: "",
    exclude: "",
    activation: "",
  },
];
const finalObj={};

array1.forEach((i)=>{
    if(finalObj[i.group])
    finalObj[i.group]["list"].push(i)
    else
        finalObj[i.group]={...i,list:[]};
})

let html="";

Object.keys(finalObj).forEach((key,i)=>{
if(key!="null")
    html+=`<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index=${i}>${key}</li>`;
    finalObj[key].list.forEach((item,j)=>{
    html+=` <li class="active-result group-option" data-option-array-index=${j+""+i}>${item.title}</li>`
    })
})


    chosenResultsUl[0].innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: this work for me, but not able to add group's 1st element, so for that added below code...           ```  

if (chosenResultsLi[key].group === null) {
        html += `<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index=${i}>${chosenResultsLiGroup[key].title}</li>`;
      } 
else {
        html += `<li class="active-result group-option" data-option-array-index=${i}>${chosenResultsLiGroup[key].title}</li>`;
      }  
 
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather from the nebulous explanation of OP is the HTML structure of the programmatically added content isn't nested properly (See **Figure I** and **II**)

**Figure I** - Undesirable HTML Layout

```html
<ul class="results">
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Group A</li>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Group B</li>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Title</li>
  <li>Title</li>
</ul>
```

**Figure II** - HTML Layout with nested `<ul>`

```html
<ul class="results">
  <li><h3>Title</h3></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><h4>Group A</h4></li>
      <li>Title</li>
      <li>Title</li>
      <li>Title</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><h4>Group B</h4></li>
      <li>Title</li>
      <li>Title</li>
      <li>Title</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** The only valid tags that can be a direct descendant (aka child element/node) of a `<ul>` are `<li>`, `<script>`, and `<template>`. Even nested `<ul>` should be within a `<li>`. A `<li>` can have anything within itself but the only tags that are valid as a `<li>`'s parent are `<ul>`, `<ol>`, and `<menu>`.

**Details are commented in example**

```js
/* .querySelector() method is more versatile than the numerous .getElement(s)By* 
   methods */
const results = document.querySelector(".results");
 /* Some property values were added as flags, they are marked below */
const data = [{
    group: "list-header", // This value is associated with template literal "header" 
    id: "all-categories",
    title: "Search All",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "list-header",
    id: "trial-catalog",
    title: "Aspire Free Products",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  },
  /* Added a "group-header" object which when rendered to HTML is a <ul> nested 
     within a <li> */
  {
    group: "group-header",
    id: "popular-product-areas",
    title: "Popular Product Areas",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "taqman-assays",
    title: "TaqMan Assays",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "gene-exp-assays",
    title: "Gene Expression",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "Popular Product Areas",
    id: "microbe-abr-detection",
    title: "Microbe & ABR Detection",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: "end", // "end" serves as a flag that indicates the last <li> of a group <ul>
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "group-header",
    id: "doc-support",
    title: "Doc Support",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "microbe-detection",
    title: "Microbe Detection",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "antibiotic-resistance",
    title: "Antibiotic Resistance",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: null,
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }, {
    group: "Doc Support",
    id: "crispr-guide-rna",
    title: "CRISPR Guide RNA",
    searchURL: null,
    typeAheadURL: null,
    include: "end",
    exclude: null,
    activation: null
  }
];
let items = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const header =
    `<li class="active list-header" data-index="${i}">
        <h3>${data[i].title}</h3>
      </li>`;

  const group =
    `<li><ul class="group-header" data-index="${i}">
        <li style="list-style:none;margin-left:-40px"><h4>${data[i].title}</h4></li> `;

  const item =
    `<li class="active item" data-group="${data[i].group}" data-index="${i}">
        <h5>${data[i].title}</h5>
      </li>`;

  if (data[i].group === "group-header") {
    items.push(group);
  } else if (data[i].group === "list-header") {
    items.push(header);
  } else {
    items.push(item);
    // if ["include"] property is "end", add closing tags
    if (data[i].include === "end") {
      items.push(`</li></ul>`);
    }
  }
}

let html = "";
if (items.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    html += items[i];
  }
}

results.innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<ul class="results"></ul>
```